# Erratic behaviours in VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, disassembly

```
if(!base_initialized())return;  

    if(strcmp(fname,name) != 0)
    {
        -->std::string strentry;

        std::stringstream ss;
```

When i put a breakpoint on the line with --> there is an erratic behaviour, it doesn't go the next line when i press F10 it just goes out of the block ..

The disassembly also seems weird to me.. it is like this.

```
if(!base_initialized())return;  

    if(strcmp(fname,name) != 0)
    {
        -->>std::string strentry;
004013F0  mov         dword ptr [esp+0Ch],ebx 
004013F4  call        dword ptr [__imp_base_initialized (4071BCh)] 
004013FA  test        eax,eax 
004013FC  je          writetohashset+2C1h (401671h) 
00401402  mov         ecx,ebx 
00401404  mov         eax,esi 
00401406  mov         dl,byte ptr [eax] 
00401408  cmp         dl,byte ptr [ecx] 
0040140A  jne         writetohashset+76h (401426h) 
    if(!base_initialized())return;  

    if(strcmp(fname,name) != 0)
0040140C  test        dl,dl 
0040140E  je          writetohashset+72h (401422h) 
00401410  mov         dl,byte ptr [eax+1] 
00401413  cmp         dl,byte ptr [ecx+1] 
00401416  jne         writetohashset+76h (401426h) 
00401418  add         eax,2 
0040141B  add         ecx,2 
0040141E  test        dl,dl 
00401420  jne         writetohashset+56h (401406h) 
00401422  xor         eax,eax 
00401424  jmp         writetohashset+7Bh (40142Bh) 
00401426  sbb         eax,eax 
00401428  sbb         eax,0FFFFFFFFh 
0040142B  test        eax,eax 
0040142D  je          writetohashset+2C1h (401671h) 
    {
        -->>std::string strentry;
00401433  lea         ecx,[esp+0B4h] 
0040143A  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > (407084h)] 

        std::stringstream ss;
```

notice the two lines with arrows. there is multiple definition for the same thing.

Comment: Are you compiling with code optimizations enabled or disabled?

Comment: dude, `strcmp`? And you tagged this code C++?

Comment: THANKS! rueben.. turned compiler optimizations off and its working fine.! :D

Comment: any thoughts on why this was happening?

Comment: It was happening because the compiler was able to figure out that the code you tried to set your breakpoint on wasn't doing anything useful, or that there was a way to do things better, so it killed it off or moved it around. Optimizers can do magic stuff with your program :-)